# Get the address of a function [Swift 3.0]

Tags: ios, swift, pointers, memory

You can get an address of `AnyObject` with `unsafeAdressOf(object:AnyObject) -> UnsafePointer<void>` function call but how can I get an address of a function? for example

```
func foo(){print("hi")}
print(unsafeAdressOf(foo))
```

does not work

Comment: No way provided. If you can show the use cases you need to get the address, someone would show you a better solution.

Comment: As a use case, how about creating a dictionary of function addresses as keys with values that are some other function to call? Then when the OS calls your validateMenuItem() function and passes you an NSMenuItem reference, you can quickly look up the action function in the dictionary and find a function to call to enable or disable the menu item without having a giant switch statement or other terrible mechanism. it avoids having to create an outlet for every menu item to do this same thing (if the menu items are even hashable themselves). Just a thought.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Foo {
    func poo(value: Int) {
        print(value)
    }
}
typealias classFunctionType = @convention(thin) (Foo)->(Int)->()

func getSwiftFunctionAddr(_ function: @escaping classFunctionType) -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer {
    return unsafeBitCast(function, to: UnsafeMutableRawPointer.self)
}

let func_addr = getSwiftFunctionAddr(Foo.poo)

print(func_addr)
```

Comment: Please add link content to your asnwer

Comment: For posterity: in the second sample, the officially unsupported `@convention(thin)` makes Swift store values of the function type `NewSwiftNSLog` as a simple pointer. Once we've tricked it into using a simple pointer, all that's left to do is to pump it through `unsafeBitCast` to smuggle the value into "user-space", as it were.

Comment: And for functions representable in C, the much more supported `@convention(c)` attribute works as well.